# Which test to use for (repeated) count/proportional data to test for differences within a categorical variable?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, proportion, count-data

**Background information**

Using different machine learning models, I predicted three different behavioural categories in cats (active, inactive, maintenance). I then created a dataframe that contained the counts and proportion of each behavioural category per day (6 days per cat; 12 cats total).

**Data**

I have a dataframe (df) that contains both the counts (Active, Inactive, Maintenance) and proportions (propAtive, propInactive, propMaintenance) of the different behavioural categories. See head and structure of the df below:

```
    Model    Cat_id    Day     Active Inactive Maintenance Total propActive propInactive propMaintenance Model2
 1: C.RF1    Cho       1 days  1936   75672    8792        86400 0.02240741    0.8758333      0.10175926  C.RF1
 2: C.RF1    Cho       2 days  1307   78236    6857        86400 0.01512731    0.9055093      0.07936343  C.RF1
 3: C.RF1    Cho       3 days  1360   73784    11256       86400 0.01574074    0.8539815      0.13027778  C.RF1
 4: C.RF1    Cho       4 days  2828   70666    12906       86400 0.03273148    0.8178935      0.14937500  C.RF1
 5: C.RF1    Cho       5 days  2988   74130    9282        86400 0.03458333    0.8579861      0.10743056  C.RF1
 6: C.RF1    Cho       6 days  1809   74477    10114       86400 0.02093750    0.8620023      0.11706019  C.RF1

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1152 obs. of  11 variables:
$ Model          : Factor w/ 16 levels "C.RF1","C.RF2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Cat_id         : Factor w/ 12 levels "Cho","George",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Day            : 'difftime' num  1 2 3 4 ...
..- attr(*, "units")= chr "days"
$ Active         : int  1936 1307 1360 2828 2988 1809 2616 2697 2540 3796 ...
$ Inactive       : int  75672 78236 73784 70666 74130 74477 74862 75588 74547 73742 ...
$ Maintenance    : int  8792 6857 11256 12906 9282 10114 8922 8115 9313 8862 ...
$ Total          : int  86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 ...
$ propActive     : num  0.0224 0.0151 0.0157 0.0327 0.0346 ...
$ propInactive   : num  0.876 0.906 0.854 0.818 0.858 ...
$ propMaintenance: num  0.1018 0.0794 0.1303 0.1494 0.1074 ...
$ Model2         : Factor w/ 16 levels "H.RF1","C.RF1",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
- attr(*, "sorted")= chr [1:3] "Model" "Cat_id" "Day"
```

**What do I want to test?**

Looking at the means for each behavioural categorie, some models seem to predict quite similarly, while some predict quite differently. Now I would like to test for significant differences in counts/proportions between the models, within each behaviour (e.g., does model C.RF1 predict active with a different proportion than C.RF2). In addition to this, I would like to see if 'Day' has an effect on the counts/proportions. So far, I have used a Dirichlet Regression to test for differences in the proportions between the models. As far as I could find, however, the Dirichlet is not quite suited for repeated measures. In addition to this, I have had some issues with the Dirichlet Regression, for which I have not found a solution yet. If you want to know the specifics of this, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290168/r-dirichreg-error-in-summary-dirichletregmodel-optimization-did-not-converge-in).

**Question**

I have tried to search for an alternative statistical test I can do to get the results I want and have found a few different possible alternatives (e.g., [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281027/repeated-measures-anova-on-percentages), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363962/what-model-to-use-with-repeated-measures-of-count-data-with-a-factor-and-a-covar), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198527/which-model-to-use-for-longitudinal-count-data)). However, I am not a statistician and do not know what test would best fit my data and question, and would really appreciate any advice regarding which test to use.

ps. In case this information is needed: I am using R to analyse my data.